# Change the size of the "Product Process Image"

Tags: product-images

The image displayed next to the Main Product image is being resized down too small.  Where can I change the setting for this?

I changed the size for the Product Process Image in the admin panel config area and saw no change.  I am looking through the file directory but haven't run into what i'm looking for.

Comment: Have you tried flushing the catalog image cache from the admin? Admin->System->Cache Management->Flush Catalog Images Cache Pregenerated product images files. Caution: This can cause slow page loads as all Images will be regenerated.